# Type for currency in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I downloaded data from Mockaroo with column price where the currency sign does exist.

```sql
create table car (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(19, 2) NOT NULL
);
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (1, 'Oldsmobile', 'Intrigue', '$754.65');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (2, 'Dodge', 'Intrepid', '$913.84');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (3, 'Chevrolet', 'S10', '$573.35');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (4, 'Ford', 'F-Series', '$528.57');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (5, 'Honda', 'Accord', '$495.70');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (6, 'Isuzu', 'Trooper', '$489.83');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (7, 'Mitsubishi', 'Eclipse', '$637.15');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (8, 'Subaru', 'Legacy', '$632.20');
insert into car (id, make, model, price) values (9, 'Mercury', 'Mountaineer', '$566.08');
```

But There is an error: invalid syntax for numeric type.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Use [money](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html) type. Be sure and read through the doc section for potential issues.

Comment: Is there an opportunity to process the downloaded data before executing it as SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A numeric column (or any "number") can't store a `$` sign. If you really need to store the currency together with the value, you need to store it in two columns:

```
create table car (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(19, 2) NOT NULL,
    currency varchar(3) NOT NULL
);

insert into car (make, model, price, currency) 
values 
('Oldsmobile', 'Intrigue', 754.65, 'USD'),
('Dodge', 'Intrepid', 913.84, 'USD'),
('Chevrolet', 'S10', 573.35, 'USD');
```

Note that you should not provide values for generated columns (neither for the discouraged bigserial nor for standard compliant identity columns)

Comment: i know this. But it is in Mockaroo web site there currency and money go together